# Get the values from the notify property with bluepy

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4, gatt

I am creating a python program on raspberry pi 4 with ubuntu on it.
The program must connect to a well-specified BLE device and get the values of a certain NOTIFY property.

these are all services and features of the BLE device. Obtained by scanning with the bluepy library

```
Service UUID: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
     -> Characteristic UUID: 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic handle: 3
        Characteristic properties: READ 
        Value: b''
     -> Characteristic UUID: 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic handle: 5
        Characteristic properties: READ 
        Value: b'\x00\x00'
     -> Characteristic UUID: 00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic handle: 7
        Characteristic properties: READ 
        Value: b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff'
Service UUID: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
     -> Characteristic UUID: 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic handle: 10
        Characteristic properties: INDICATE 
Service UUID: 00001523-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123
     -> Characteristic UUID: 00001027-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123
        Characteristic handle: 13
        Characteristic properties: READ WRITE 
     -> Characteristic UUID: 00001011-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123
        Characteristic handle: 15
        Characteristic properties: NOTIFY 
Service UUID: 0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
     -> Characteristic UUID: 00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic handle: 19
        Characteristic properties: NOTIFY
```

The services that interest me are the last two UUIDs, the BLE Scanner application also confirms.

To get the value of notify I use the following code

```
def threadWrite(characteristic, peripheral):
    # is the Characteristic UUID: 00001027-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123
    characteristic.write(b"reset\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    characteristic.write(b"read ppg 4\n")
    time.sleep(1)

    peripheral.setDelegate(classes.MyDelegate())
    svc = peripheral.getServiceByUUID("00001523-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123")
    ch = svc.getCharacteristics("00001011-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123")[0]
    ch_cccd = ch.getDescriptors(forUUID=0x2902)[0]
    ch_cccd.write(b"\0x1\x00")

    characteristic.write(b"read ppg 5\n")

    while True:
        if peripheral.waitForNotifications(1.0):
            # handleNotification() was called
            continue
        print("Waiting...")

//different module
class MyDelegate(btle.DefaultDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        btle.DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)

    def handleNotification(self, cHandle, data):
        print ("Notification received: handle =", cHandle, "; Raw data =", binascii.b2a_hex(data))
```

I checked the commands I send with peripheral.writeCharacteristic and they actually arrive at the device because the scan starts; even then connecting with BLE Scanner I see the NOTIFY values update.

The problem is that I only get the NOTIFY value of the last service: 0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb - handle: 19.
Instead I need the NOTIFY of the Characteristic UUID: 00001011-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123 - handle: 15

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: The notify value is initially "null" but when I send the command to the device, the value constantly updates and changes.
I'm 99% sure the value is changing but bluepy fails to catch the notification.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not enabling the notifications. This is done by sending `1` (as an int16 little endian value) to the descriptor with a UUID of `0x2902` (which is a standard Bluetooth UUID so can also be written in full as `00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`).

So the start of your code needs to look like:

```py
    peripheral.setDelegate(classes.MyDelegate(ch.getHandle())
    svc = peripheral.getServiceByUUID("00001523-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123")
    ch = svc.getCharacteristics("00001011-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123")[0]
    ch_cccd = ch.getDescriptors(forUUID=0x2902)[0]
    ch_cccd.write(b"\0x1\x00")
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response but I keep getting the NOTIFY which I don't care about.
I updated the code with your tips.
If it can be useful with BLT Scanner I see in the Notify Characteristic:
`DESCRIPTOR
0x1 Client Characteristic Configuration (2902)`

Comment: is it not possible to change the peripheral.setDelegate to look at a specific notify? @ukBaz

Comment: The documentation says "cHandle is the (integer) handle for the characteristic - this can be used to distinguish between notifications from multiple sources on the same peripheral." https://ianharvey.github.io/bluepy-doc/delegate.html#handleNotification. You were passing in the `cHandle` to the `MyDelegate` class __init.__. Can you not use that to filter how it responds?

Comment: filtering cHandles simply discards the ones that trigger you until you get the one I'm interested in. not?
My problem is that I just get the cHandle wrong, like listening to only one notify.
Is the code right?

Comment: You are correct, passing the cHandles will only remove those that you are not interested in. What you are showing looks correct so I suspect that the error is elsewhere in the code you haven't shown. Try to build a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so you can share it all.

Comment: data reception is 80 bytes. could this be a problem somehow?